# Gdal merging every two images

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have two sets of MODIS imagery, changed and re-projected to GEOTIFF:
1.includes the south part of my region (100 images)
2.includes the north part of my region (100 images)
I want to merge them into one file for each date.
for example at May 1st, I have one image covering north, one covering south...and I want to merge them into one... Also for May 2nd, 3rd and for all later dates.
Any idea how to do that automatically?

Comment: What's the file naming convention? Can you extract the date directly from the name, or do you need to look at results of gdalinfo to determine image metadata?

Comment: Yes, we can see DOY from the file name … example: MOD*.A2013145.h11v04.006.* …. that means year 2013, DOY:145

Comment: OK, based on [this example blog](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2015/01/using-gdalwarp-to-mosaic-adjacent-geo.html) the general code at a command line is `gdalwarp img1 img2 imgoutput`. Are you more comfortable in bash/command line tools or in something like Python? What OS are you using (does it support bash scripting?)

Comment: I am using windows, and I have access to both Bash and Python. like the example you provided, I used gdalwarp .... but I can not make it like an automatic process.

Comment: For clarification, what have you tried and where are you getting stuck? I'm thinking loop through dates grabbing related files (or maybe just putting related files in a tuple/list structure) and creating output filename / issuing gdalwarp command.

Comment: My problem is exactly that! I am not professional and I don't have any idea how to do it on a loop! I just know how to do it manually with 2 images at a time.

Comment: OK. I'd move this to chat but a) not sure how and b) I don't think your current rep would allow you to respond. Let's break the problem down into chunks: a) identify the related images b) create a standardized output name, presumably based on the input name and c) issue the command. Starting with 3, let's verify that Python in your setup can handle this. [Subprocess](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators) module in Python can call system commands. Please verify that module works in your setup.

Comment: Yes Subprocess works in my setup

Comment: Next let's try to tackle the grouping of related images. Are the dates always in the same position in the file name (number of characters) or is the position variable? Are you working only within 2013, or multiple years? We could use something like [regular expressions](https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs), or simple string matching. If sorted in name order, do the matching images appear sequentially (i.e. even position in list order = N, odd position in list order = S)? If so that would make our job easiest.

Comment: 1. the dates are always in the same position in the file name. 
2. Only working with 2013 now
3. matching images appear sequentially

Comment: checking in to make sure this answered your question. Once you've had a chance to test please accept if it worked, or post additional information.

Comment: Sorry for answering late, the code gives an error of Invalid syntax

Comment: Please edit to include your code and the error message (including error details such as the line number).

Comment: I used the code you provided, and it gives error in line "for i in range(0, len(fnames), 2)" …. added comments on the code where it gives error

Comment: The issue with that line was a missing colon. Updated to include the colon (for loops syntax always end with colon, just like if statements).

Comment: Oh I see, I also added a colon in the similar line ( for date checking loop)...removing "if"  and adding "=" for that loop... and it's working

Comment: Great! Fast coding with no access to test = coding errors. Welcome to your first Python script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answers in the comments about the general data setup, try this Python-based script. It may need to be modified further for your details. This     assumes you have gdal installed in a way that is accessible from the command line but not necessarily within Python.

```
# import dependencies
import subprocess
import os

# Identify matching files. There are many ways to do this! 
# Here I'm taking advantage of the sequential nature of the 
# matching files, but to be on the safe side we'll sort it first.

# Get a list of the TIFs in your current directory
fnames = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'): 
    fnamestmp = [fi for fi in files if fi.endswith('.tif')]  
    # list comprehension filtering for TIF files. 
    # You could do this in separate lines if you prefer.  
    # See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176441/how-to-filter-files-with-known-type-from-os-walk.  
    # Uses a temporary list in case you have subfolders.
    fnames.extend(fnamestmp)  # adds to the end of the existing list

#files should appear in the list in order, but sort just in case
fnames.sort()  

# Verify dates match (optional)
for i in range(0, len(fnames), 2): # start from beginning, skip every other file
    if fnames[i][startingdateposition:endingdateposition+1] == if fnames[i+1][startingdateposition:endingdateposition+1]:
        print "dates match!"


# Submit each process.  
# May want to build in a wait period or some way of checking 
# whether the process is done before moving on. 
# (time.sleep? os.wait? Some way of checking subprocess? subprocess.popen instead of call? 
# search the site for more info on these methods.)
for i in range(0, len(fnames), 2): # start from beginning, skip every other file
    outputfname = "merged" + fnames[i+1][startingdateposition:endingdateposition+1] + '.tif' # update code for what you want your filenames to be. Probably want output in a different folder too.
    args = ['gdalwarp', fnames[i], fnames[i+1], outputfname]
    subprocess.call(args)
```